# ¿Por qué jsonArrayRequest no guarda valores si trabajo fuera del método?

Tags: java, android-studio, webservice

Tengo un problema con `JSON`, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación en ***Android Studio*** que se conecta a una base de datos externa por medio de `web servers`. He creado una clase que contiene el método donde se guardan los datos en `ArrayList<String>`:

```
package com.isai.testriesgo5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BaseDatosExtern {

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> arreglo = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor
    public BaseDatosExtern( Context context ){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void BuscarUsuario( String url ){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                arreglo.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        String myString = jsonObject.getString("id_usuario");
                        arreglo.add( myString );

                        myString = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                        byte[] ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("contrasena");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("correo");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("edad");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("genero");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("carrera");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("vivienda");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("contrasena");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("trabajo");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("horario_sueno");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("actividad");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );
                        myString = jsonObject.getString("fecha_registros");
                        ptext = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                        arreglo.add( value );

                    } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                }
             Toast.makeText(context, arreglo.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( context );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    /*Metodo para enviar el arreglo*/
    public ArrayList<String> getArreglo(){
        return this.arreglo;
    }
}
```

En la clase principal simplemente llamo al método para trabajar con los datos:

```
btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Datos datos = new Datos();
                BaseDatosExtern baseDatosExtern = new BaseDatosExtern( getContext() );
                String url = "http://" + datos.getIp() + ":" + datos.getPuerto()
                        +"/programacion/webserverandroid2/buscarUsuario.php?nombre="
                        + editNombre.getText().toString() + "";

                baseDatosExtern.BuscarUsuario( url );

                );
            }
        });
```

El web services trabaja bien. Cuando ejecuto la aplicación e inicio sesión se muestra en ***Android*** (por el método `Toast`) el nombre del usuario.

Mi duda o mi pregunta radica en por que si comento esta linea en la clase BaseDatosExtern

```
Toast.makeText(context, arreglo.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Y con el método `getArreglo()` de esta clase me retorna que el arreglo no contiene datos?.
¿Existe alguna forma para que yo pueda guardar los datos de ***JSon*** y obtenerlos con `getArreglo()`?